# Applying Inverse function theorem to bijective map

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, diffeomorphism

> Let $f: M \to N$ be a smooth map and $(f_*)_p: T_pM \to T_{f(p)}N$ an
> isomorphism. Then there exists an open neighborhood $W$ of $p$ such
> that $f\vert_W: W \to f(W)$ is a diffeomorphism.

This theorem is called inverse function theorem.

My question: If $f$ is bijective, can we say every open neighborhood $W$ of $p$,$f\vert_W: W \to f(W)$ is a diffeomorphism ?

If it is true, how can I prove that?

Comment: Can you show that $f^{-1}$ is smooth (hint: it's a local condition)?

Comment: I don't sure, I want to know where I use the condition f is bijective

Comment: Saying that $f|_V : V \to f(V)$ is a diffeomorphism already include that $f^{-1}|_{f(V)} : f(V) \to V$ is smooth.

Comment: You also have to check the condition that the Jacobian is non singular when it's evaluated in a point $p$ of the manifold